# MVC - where to put communication code

Tags: model-view-controller, networking

I want to try to write (amateur here!) a multiplayer game, and now at designing I decided to use the MVC-pattern.
Now my question is: where should I put my networking code? In the Model or the Controller? (Obviously not the View)

**EDIT:**
Sorry, for the hundredst time my question was unclear.
The game itself will be MVC, and it will firstly communicate with a server (find player), and later with that player (send your turn and get other's turn). So where should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the actual game itself in a new project and reference that between your MVC application, that way your game is entirely separated from your web application.  This could be useful if you ever wanted to port it to WPF for instance. Another alternative is to have the game as Web Service which the MVC application requests information from and would provide scalability for additional languages to plugin in.

However, if you decide to keep everything as a whole in MVC then I would suggest the Model.

As a breakdown:

- The controller takes care of all the web requests, i.e. GET and POST. It can also populate a model and return the appropriate view for that request.
- The model contains the domain objects and logic to perform (i.e. extracting information from the repository and manipulating the data to be passed to the view).
- The view returns the markup which is based upon the data stored within the model.

In certain implementations additional logic such as checking conditions and Repository calls also take place at the controller level, which is a technique known as Fat Controller Thin Model.

**Edit:**

You should be sending a request to the controller.  I.e.  In your games controller have a `HTTPPost` method that connects to the server and then sends the players turn info and gets the new information.  For example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendPlayerTurnInformation(PlayerObject player) 
{
   // logic to connect to the Game Network
   // connection.UpdatePlayerTurn(player);

   //return success/fail
}
```

You could then do the same to get a specific players turn information and then update your model to be passed to the view which would contain the new information.

Comment: *Small note*: if your controller is extracting information from model layer and passing it to view, then you are actually implementing MVP. In classical MVC and Model2 MVC design patters the view is active, in MVP and MVVM - it is passive.

Comment: @tereško - the controller does not extract information from the model. From my description, I was referring to the repository as a database connection or the game network.  I used the fat controller thin model as an example, personally I do not implement solutions using this method.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC design pattern is actually a combination of two layers: presentation layer and model layer. Presentation layer usually deals with user interface (updates it and reacts to user's interaction). The model layer deals with domain business logic and persistence.

The networking code should go in the model layer.

To be exact, in the part of model layer, that deals with persistence, because there, from the standpoint of  business logic, there is no difference where the data comes from. It can be from the SQL database, from opened network socket or detector on the mars rover. Those all are just data sources, which, often implemented as [data mappers](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), are part of the model layer.

Comment: Yes, so what is the problem ? You are not only *getting data* from SQL either. It's obvious, that model layer's interaction with storage medium is two-way.

Comment: Hmm... Thinks the edit of Darren Davies makes more sense. Still, +1.